# Flowplayer jQuery Tools not functioning in IE 7/8

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, flowplayer

I've noticed an issue which has recently cropped up regarding Flowplayer's jQuery Tools, which do not appear to be functioning in IE 7/8.  Please reference [here](http://www.aifittingsproto.com/catalog/emt-fittings/combination-set-screw-emt-and-threaded-rigid/).  Works great in Safari/Firefox/IE9, - and was in IE7/8 until recently.  Is anyone aware of a conflict between jQuery1.6 and jQueryTools 1.2.5 which might be causing this issue?  Any feedback and suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: jQuery Tools version 1.2.5 was last updated for jQuery 1.4.2 over a year ago.  It's no wonder you're finding some issues with jQuery 1.6.  In the Flowplayer forums, there are also some reports of issues with IE9, but again, jQuery Tools was last updated before IE9 was released.  The developer disappeared for many months and then he returned to say he would re-write jQuery Tools from scratch.  This is yet to happen but even if it does, he already stated that the new version will not be backward compatible with existing code.  My advice, if you have to start over, you might as well move on.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback...more than likely will have to develop from scratch, or at least make accommodations for IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by fixing the javascript syntax error on this line:

```
<script>var x=0;function sendEmail(x){document.getElementById("rep_email").value=x;document.getElementById("zip_code").value=;document.locate_rep.submit()}function sendButton(){document.email_rep.submit_email.style.width="150px";document.email_rep.submit_email.value="Sending...Please Wait"}$(document).ready(function(){$("input").each(function(){$(this).data("placeholder",$(this).val())});$("input").live("focus",function(){if($(this).val()==$(this).data("placeholder")){$(this).val('')}});$("input").live("blur",function(){if(!$(this).val().length){$(this).val($(this).data("placeholder"))}})});</script>    </div>
```

It's this part of that line which is obviously missing the right-hand part of the assignment:

```
document.getElementById("zip_code").value=;
```

Beyond that, can you tell us what functionality on the page isn't working and give us some idea what code might be related to that feature?  Please remember that we don't know your page so don't even have an idea where the flow player is on your page or what else might not be working.

Comment: The horizontal scrollbox and and tabs box are utilizing flowplayer's jquerytools.  Within IE7/8 the tabs are being shown; however, the tab content is not being displayed, making me think that the show() calls are not being executed correctly.  For the aforementioned js "error" the zip value is being populated with PHP after a value is entered into the form.  I suppose I could default it to 0 or "".